# ThingsBoard whitelabelling Menu Item cannot be found

Tags: thingsboard, white-labelling

We have ThingsBoard white labelling as part of our subscription. My colleagues who is currently on holidays applied it a while ago and we have our logo, etc; yesterday while trying to change something I realized I don't have the white labelling menu item on the left. I am a "Tenant Administrator" but the white labelling menu item is no where to be seen. Any ideas how it can be turned back on again?

I have already looked in the "settings" but the only relevant items found there are "Home Settings" Tab which is set to one of our Dashboards and the "Domain" Tab which has the domain which we want to map to that Dashboard whose value for the type CNAME is "thingsboard.cloud". Also the user activation link starts with the above "Domain" instead of thingsboard.cloud domain which obviously fails to resolve and would not work; so currently can't send out user activation links either.

Any ideas on resolution would be appreciated.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the white labeling your colleague set up included hiding the white labeling menu item itself from the navigation panel.

If you have the permissions, this is just a make-up mod; so you can try to access directly form the URL, adding the white labeling route:

```
https://your.tbd.domain/white-labeling/whiteLabel
```

Comment: Thanks Andres, your diagnosis was correct. I've also just realized that as you say it can be accessed by using the direct url route even if it is turned off .

Answer (score 0):

Please try to log in as System Administrator user. Perhaps your colleague defined the White-Labeling options via System Admin user and has hidden the area for Tenant Admins.

Alternatively, if there are multiple Tenant Admin groups: Maybe your group has not the sufficient access rights to view/change the white-labeling setttings.